# How to setup Clickatell

Tags: wordpress, sms

I am having issues trying to setup Clickatell SMS provider, I am running Civi 4.6.26 on wordpress 4.7.5 using the clickatell extension 3.0 and have a Clickatell Platform account.

I keep getting "ERR: 001, Authentication failed" I am not sure why I have checked the username and password, and I can log into the Clickatell portal using those details.

I have tried putting in the "api_id=" in front of the api key but then it says it is invalid.

[image: SMS provider details]

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the [current docs for setup of CiviCRM / Clickatell](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Setting+up+a+SMS+Provider+for+CiviSMS#SettingupaSMSProviderforCiviSMS-clickatell).

In that there's an example that suggests `api_key=XXX` is the correct format. It gives this example (when using a specific 2-way config):

```
api_id=1234567
from=15558238168
mo=1
```

Those docs also give instructions to [set up an API product and obtain the key (which it looks like you've done)](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Setting+up+a+SMS+Provider+for+CiviSMS#SettingupaSMSProviderforCiviSMS-clickatell), and say *"Be aware that your Clickatell API password may differ from your Clickatell account password."* which may be the problem you're hitting?

If you're getting a meaningful "authorization failed" response back I'd be inclined to take that as it is given and verify those authorization details (username, API password and API key) are configured right.

Next steps might be to debug [around this line](https://github.com/veda-consulting/org.civicrm.sms.clickatell/blob/master/org_civicrm_sms_clickatell.php#L188) to see if the parameters are being set correctly, or to seek out support from someone able to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I did follow the docs instructions, clickatell helped me out apparently I had signed up to the wrong type of account that's why it did not work I got the right account now and the Doc instructions worked like a charm